# IT Hit WebDav protocol installer fails with Firefox

Tags: firefox, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am using the latest version of Firefox (57.0.4) to test my IT Hit WebDav server implementation. When I attempt to open a file other than MS Office I expect to be prompted to install the protocol installer. Rather than being prompted I get a dialog that says I need to install something from the Windows App Store. I see the same behavior with Edge.

Both Chrome and IE are behaving as expected. It appears to be [supported by Firefox](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/open-doc-webpage/install/).

I also tested using the [Ajax browser](https://www.ajaxbrowser.com/) on Firefox and it fails as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413189/protocol-install-callback-function-is-called-even-after-the-protocol-plugin-is-i/

Answer (score 0):

The issue with Firefox is fixed in the IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library v5.

You can find a detailed answer about why the protocol app is not detected and the callback is called [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413189/protocol-install-callback-function-is-called-even-after-the-protocol-plugin-is-i/).